# IBM Domino 9.0.1 FP8 won't load plugin requiring JavaSE-1.8

Tags: xpages

I am developing an OSGi plugin to be used on our Domino 9.0.1 FP8 server.
Since the server has support for Java 8 and I have some Java 8 code, I added:

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

in the `MANIFEST.MF`.

However, when I try to load the plugin, it remains stuck in the `INSTALLED` state:

```
tell http osgi ss com.test.api.plugin
Framework is launched.
id       State       Bundle
19       INSTALLED   com.test.api.plugin_0.1.0.201706241509
```

Running diagnostics reveals that the execution environment is not available:

```
tell http osgi diag com.test.api.plugin
initial@osginsf:apps.nsf/0D3C92BFD9106A9DC125814900535ABD/com.test.api.plugin_0.1.0.201706241509.jar [19]
Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

Just to be sure, I double-checked the Java version:

```
show jvm
JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
Java runtime version: pwa6480sr3fp22-20161213_02 (SR3 FP22)
JVM version: JRE 1.8.0 Windows 8 amd64-64 Compressed References 20161209_329148 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) J9VM - R28_20161209_1345_B329148 JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20161207_128946 GC   - R28_20161209_1345_B329148_CMPRSS J9CL - 20161209_329148
```

So, everything seems to be in order, but the plugin won't load.

If I change the required execution environment to JavaSE-1.6 or if I remove the line from `MANIFEST.MF`, the plugin loads and works just fine.

My temporary solution is to remove the line completely from the `MANIFEST.MF` since Java 8 code won't compile if I change execution environment to JavaSE-1.6.

So I have a working solution, but I would like to know what the problem is and if there is a better way to solve it.

Another thing I noticed: I usually use Maven for building plugins, but if I try to export the plugin from Eclipse using `Export > Deployable plug-ins and fragments`, I get the following error:

```
Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Host plug-in JavaSE_0.0.0 has not been found.
```

Switching to JavaSE-1.6 helps even here and the plugin gets exported correctly.

Could this be an OSGi version issue instead of a Java issue?

I seem to remember that there should be an OSGi update in FP9. Is there a chance that this will be solved then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the reason for this is indeed what you mentioned towards the end: it's the OSGi stack. Though the underlying runtime is Java 8, IBM didn't update the OSGi stack at all (barring anything that would have been required, I guess), and that includes it not knowing that it's on a Java 8 runtime. Assuming that FP9 does indeed arrive with the OSGi update, that should presumably clean it up.

In the mean time, I've been doing the same thing you did: remove the line from the manifest and just deal with the warning (and I use a Maven build to generate the update site all the time out of habit, so didn't hit the second error).

Comment: Same old story with partial updates, then :-)
Not too big of a problem, though. I can live with a warning in the MANIFEST.MF. Hopefully it gets sorted out in FP9.

Comment: Same as Jesse, I remove the Bundle-Execution Environment and always use an Update Site. I think Java 8 was only ever the extent of FP8, OSGi and Notes were FP9. The preference amongst plugin developers in the community was to split it, so we got Java 8 for compiling in plugins asap. It's not a decision I've regretted since the delivery.